# Split dataset file in parts of a specific size

Tags: r, import, split, dataset, size

I want to analyze [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/unitednations/global-commodity-trade-statistics/home) on a system that limits the imports to 100MBs at a time.

How should one split a dataset, per rows, into a max of 100MBs parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read the dataset.
2. Split the dataset into 14 chunks (in 13 chunks I had a file with over 100MB).
3. Then I saved the result back as a csv using `purrr`

Here is the script I used:

```
trade = read.csv("commodity_trade_statistics_data.csv")

no_of_chunks <- 14

f <- ceiling(1:nrow(trade) / nrow(trade) * 14)

res <- split(trade, f)

library(purrr)
map2(res, paste0("chunk_", names(res), ".csv"), write.csv)
```